# C,BST, Pnode lost in the dictionary

Tags: c

I have, two follows Structures

```
typedef struct dictionary {
    int n_data;
    PNODO tree; 
} DICC, *PDICC;

typedef struct nodo {
    int info;
    struct nodo *l;
    struct nodo *r;
} NODO, *PNODO;
```

And the the next functions to create them:

```
PDICC ini_dicctionary(void) {
    PDICC pdicc;  
    if (!(pdicc = (PDICC) malloc(sizeof(PDICC))))
        return NULL;
    pdicc->n_data = 0;
    return pdicc;
}

PNODO ini_nodo(void) {
    PNODO pnodo;   
    if (!(pnodo = (PNODO) calloc(1, sizeof (PNODO))))
        return NULL;    
    pnodo->info = -1;
    return pnodo;
}
```

Both works properly, but when I insert a key in my tree, the node information is lost, like it wasn't a pointer, I tried many things like change all my functions to use a double pointer, but when I do it, valgrind reports invalids reads (but all works properly). I'm tring not to use a double pointer, but I'm getting nothing.

```
int insert_dictionary(PDICC pdicc, int key) {
    int ob = 0;
    if (!pdicc)
        return ERR;
    ob = insert_nodo(key, pdicc->tree);
    if (ob != ERR) {
        pdicc->n_data += 1;
        return ob;
    }
    return ERR;
}

int insert_nodo(int key, PNODO pnodo) {
    int ob = 0;
    if (!pnodo) {
        pnodo = ini_nodo();
        pnodo->info = key;
        return ob;
    }
    ob += 1;
    if (key == pnodo->info) {
        return ERR;
    }
    else if (key <= pnodo->info)
        ob += insert_nodo(key, pnodo->l);
    else
        ob += insert_nodo(key, pnodo->r);
    return ob;
}
```

Comment: `pdicc = (PDICC) malloc(sizeof(PDICC)` is this what you want? PDICC is already a `struct dictionary *`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and *stop hiding pointer types in `typedef` aliases*. Until you know, and I mean *really know*, what you're doing, it does the exact opposite of being helpful.

Comment: I deleted the (PDICC) casting, but the problem still there, the problem is that when call insert_nodo(), the pointer is lost and the root of the tree is null.

Comment: 1) `pdicc = (PDICC) malloc(sizeof(PDICC))` --> `pdicc = (PDICC) malloc(sizeof(*pdicc))` and `pnodo = (PNODO) calloc(1, sizeof (PNODO))` --> `pnodo = (PNODO) calloc(1, sizeof (*pnode))` : `sizeof(PDICC)` is pointer size, not struct dictionary size.

Comment: 2) `pnodo = ini_nodo();` : no effect. because `pnode` is local variabel.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is that when call insert_nodo(), the pointer is lost and
>   the root of the tree is null.

That's because you pass the root of the tree *by value* to `insert_nodo()`, hence it can't be altered, as BLUEPIXY hinted at with the comment

> 2) `pnodo = ini_nodo();` : no effect. because
>   `pnode` is local variabel.

You'd have to make the following changes:

```
    ob = insert_nodo(key, &pdicc->tree);    // pass tree by address
…
int insert_nodo(int key, PNODO *ppnodo) {
    int ob = 0;
    if (!*ppnodo) {
        *ppnodo = ini_nodo();
        (*ppnodo)->info = key;
        return ob;
    }
    ob += 1;
    if (key == (*ppnodo)->info) {
        return ERR;
    }
    else if (key < (*ppnodo)->info)
        ob += insert_nodo(key, &(*ppnodo)->l);
    else
        ob += insert_nodo(key, &(*ppnodo)->r);
    return ob;
}
```